# Wildcard Nested Routes in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

How would you accomplish a deeply nested wildcard route with the Angular 2 router. All the wildcard sample code tends to deal with Page Not Found examples. Suppose the following use case. You had a program that acts as a folder viewer on a file system. Example routes might include:

- `/home/Documents/Personal`
- `/home/Pictures/Vacation/2015`
- `/home/Pictures/Vacations/2015/10`

So far I have tried the following:

```
const r = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '**',
        component: FolderViewerComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

This kind of works. I can access the the URL and the parts with the following:

```
export class FolderViewerComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.route.url);
  }
}
```

However, when I navigate around the same the ngOnInit is not triggered again since the new route uses the same component. Hence, I don't have a way to request the new folder contents from the server.

So at the end of the day:

1. Is there a better way I should be doing this?
2. If not is there an event I can subscribe to when the route changes, even if the component does not?

Comment: just store the url in an vaiable and check with with this variable everytime with the new url

Comment: ngOnInit() { this.route.params.forEach(params: Params) => {  //write code here }) }`

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking there might be a better approach, but based on some comments I finally I settled on the following. Basically I subscribe to route changes and execute code when it changes.

```
import {Component, OnInit, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  template: `...`
})
export class FolderViewerComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  url: string;
  routeSub: Subscription;

  constructor(private router: Router) {
  }

  handleRouteChange(event) {
    if (this.url !== event.url) {
      this.url = event.url;
      console.log(`Route changed to ${this.url}`);
      // Whatever code you want
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.routeSub = this.router.events.subscribe(this.handleRouteChange);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.routeSub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```